# vb.net imports wrong data from excel into datagridview

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, type-conversion

i encountered a problem during importing data from excel to datagridview in VB.net.
And i dont know or where to start to search for the problem. Here's the situation:
I have an excel file,

```
Column A(General)     Column B(Time)

 Adarayan, Dianne       6:00 AM
 Bacalla, Cruz          1:30 PM
 Mariano, Kevin           RD
 Roses, Alice             VL
 Ligris, Paul           RD/OT 7:30
```

Output/ Display in datagridview:

```
 Team Member            TimeSchedule

 Adarayan, Dianne         0.25
 Bacalla, Cruz            0.5625
 Mariano, Kevin           RD
 Roses, Alice             VL
 Ligris, Paul           RD/OT 7:30
```

I dont know why this happens, when the string is like the first 2 rows it displays float.
Please help guys.

This is my code in importing data from excel to datagridview.

```
  OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files 2007 (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Excel Files 1997-2003 (*.xls)|*.xls"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        Try

            xlsApp = New Excel.Application
            xlsWorkBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            xlsWorkSheet = xlsWorkBook.Worksheets("WORK SCHEDULE")
            'unprotect file 
            'Get last row used 
            'lastUsedRow = xlsWorkSheet.Range("I" & xlsWorkSheet.Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
            'Get last column 
            'lastUsedCol = xlsWorkSheet.Cells(1, xlsWorkSheet.Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column

            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            Dim sConnectionStringz As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"""
            Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionStringz)
            objConn.Open()
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            Dim start As Integer
            Dim ends As Integer


            For Each c In xlsWorkSheet.Range("B1:B300").Cells
                If IsNothing(c.value) Then
                    x = x + 1
                ElseIf Not IsNothing(c.Value) Then
                    x = x + 1
                    If c.value.ToString.ToUpper <> "START" And c.value.ToString.ToUpper <> "END" Then
                    ElseIf c.value.ToString.ToUpper = "START" Then
                        start = x
                    ElseIf c.value.ToString.ToUpper = "END" Then
                        ends = x
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            Dim campaign = start + 1
            For Each c In xlsWorkSheet.Range("B" & campaign & ":B" & campaign).Cells
                If Not IsNothing(c.value) Then
                    campaignName = c.value.ToString
                End If
            Next

            Dim objAdapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [WORK SCHEDULE$B" & start & ":I" & ends & "]", objConn)
            Dim objDataset1 As New DataSet
            objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataset1.Tables(0).DefaultView
            With DataGridView1
                .RowHeadersVisible = False
                .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Team Members"
                .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Monday"
                .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Tuesday"
                .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Wednesday"
                .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Thursday"
                .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Friday"
                .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Saturday"
                .Columns(7).HeaderCell.Value = "Sunday"
            End With
            objConn.Close()
        Finally

    End Try
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your times are being converted to decimal. You will need to read them in as a time but this will cause problems where the column values are text eg. RD, VL, RD/OT 7:30
I would suggest that your excel spreadsheet has this data split over two columns eg Type and Time so you have...

```
Column A(General)     Column B(Type) Column C(Time)
Adarayan, Dianne                     6:00 AM
Bacalla, Cruz                        1:30 PM
Mariano, Kevin            RD
Roses, Alice              VL
Ligris, Paul             RD/OT       7:30 AM
```

Comment: thank you so much for the time, but is there another way where i could just convert the second row which is in time to string so that it would display the right data?

Comment: There are always more ways to skin a cat... as they say. If you can't split the data in excel you will need to write code that will check what is in the data and pull out what you need. It's not a route I would like to take unless there was no other choice.

Comment: I already have a code for this: TRIM(FORMAT(F2, 'hh:mm AM/PM')), but only the 6:00 AM is converted as 12:25 AM which is wrong.

Comment: It seems you need advice on excel formulas (not my area or expertise)... Also can I suggest you use 24h format it may be easier in the long run.